# How can I select the nth dropdown list in a table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using JQuery version 1.8.11 with IE10.

I have a table with a single row. The table id is `#listTable`, the `<tr>` id is `#listTableRow` and the `<td>` id is `#days`.

The row has a number of cells and in each cell there is a dropdown list with the same id: `#searchString`.  I want to be able to select the the dropdown list in the third cell and set its option to `option:first`. I’ve been able to select the `td` with the code below but not the specific dropdown list. How can I select the 3rd dropdown list in a table?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var nos = $('#listTable #searchString').length;

    $.each($checkboxes, function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#listTable #days:nth-child(3)').css('border', '2px dashed blue');             
    });

  });                 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select the the dropdown list in the third cell and set its option to option:first

```
$('#listTable td').eq(2).find("#searchString option:first").prop('selected', true);
```